# Flex - Propagating event from a built-in component to a custom event

Tags: apache-flex, event-handling

I am trying to understand event propagation in Flex framework and have a following doubt on it:

**Scenario:** I have a built-in component `DropDownList` on `change` of which I want to create a custom event `refreshPreview` and want to propagate it to a custom component `PictureComponent`.

In the custom component's mxml, I have added the Metadata directive as follows to register a `refreshPreview` event with the compiler

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="refreshPreview", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>
```

**Layout Details:** In my main mxml application I have laid out `DropDownList` and the custom component such that both are siblings (i.e. have a common indirect parent)
e.g.

```
<s:Group id="contentGroup">
    <s:Group id="formGroup">
        <s:Form x="11"
                y="86">
            <s:FormItem label="Employee:">
                <!-- Built-in component -->
                <s:DropDownList id="dropDownList"
                                dataProvider="{employeesCollection}"
                                labelField="LASTNAME">
                </s:DropDownList>
            </s:FormItem>
        </s:Form>
    </s:Group>

    <s:Group id="pictureGroup">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <!-- Custom Component -->
        <p:PictureComponent x="360"
                            y="2"
                            employee="{new Employee(dropDownList.selectedItem.ID,firstName.text, lastName.text)}"
                            refreshPreview="picturecomponent1_refreshPreviewHandler(event)">
        </p:PictureComponent>
    </s:Group>
</s:Group>
```

Also I have added event listeners on the built-in component in the init() method called on creationComplete event:

```
    // Initializes this component
    private function init():void
    {
        //add event listeners for dropDownList
        dropDownList.addEventListener(IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE, employeeChangeEventHandler);
    }
```

And here is the event handler for handling the built-in component event and preparing the custom event and dispatching it:

```
    private function employeeChangeEventHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
    {
        var eventObject:Event=new Event("refreshPreview");
        dispatchEvent(eventObject);
    }
```

I am seeing that the `refreshPreview` event is not getting propagated to the custom component.

**I doubt this is because the built-in component is a sibling of the target (where the event got generated) and not a parent. If that's the reason could you please help me know how to make `refreshPreview` event propagate to custom component?**

Comment: Are you making the call to dispatchEvent from within the PictureComponent?  It looks like from your code this is all script that's in the same scope as the MXML above, if that's the case then dispatching the event from that scope isn't correct, you need to give pictureComponent an id and dispatch the event from that object for it to hit your handler.

Comment: @shaunhusain, the dispatchEvent() is called in the dropDownList's `change` handler. I want the event to be propagated to `pictureComponent` (that might not necessary mean that the event itself needs to be triggered there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your DropDownList MXML, add this:

```
<s:change>
    dispatchEvent(new Event('refreshPreview', true));//true allows it to bubble out of your View
</s:change>
```

Note that a Flash event with a string that is not one of the Event Class constants is *not* a custom Event. It is a Flash Event with a different type parameter. A custom Event would be writing your own Event Class, which you do not need to do.

Note that shaunhusain is correct...the way you have this structured, PictureComponent is not going to respond to an Event in the parent View, but in itself. I wouldn't get in the habit of dispatching events on sibling Views.  Instead, I'd have the parent View set some property on the PictureComponent or bind a property in PictureComponent to the selected item in dropDownList.

Comment: thanks for the response. Could you please clarify if in Flex event could be propagated to siblings too? Please consider the MXML code above, would the event triggered at Built in component can ever reach the custom component? (check the XML comments to identify the components)

Comment: Hey @peakit, the event will always propagate outward from children to parents, never across siblings.  If your component dispatches this event internally then it would definitely reach any parent (with bubbling on parents of those components parents) but it will never propagate "sideways" across siblings.  Imagine the amount of events that would be getting dispatched if every event caused code to execute on everything in the display list tree, this would get out of control fast.

Comment: I would personally just have the change handler call the event handler for the "custom event" directly rather than having pictureComponent.dispatch(new Event()), there may be reasons to do this on occasion but as stated in the comment it's not the intention of events to work this way, rather they allow you to decouple the children from the parents.

Comment: I agree with shaunhusain. You can do this, but it's a bad habit to get into, and I prefer to give people help in developing good habits. You never know whose code you might wind up inheriting.

Comment: This worked fine. I added a custom event and event type in the custom component. Events in the custom component which require the outside world to know, are dispatched as `refreshPreview` event. The outside world handles this event based on the need. (I am new to event-driven programming hence got confused. Thanks for the guidance)